# Help with a SOQL query on ContentDocument object

Tags: soql

I tried the query below which doesn't work

```
select id, title from contentdocument where not title like '%seo%' and filetype = 'pdf'
```

But if I write, it works

```
select id, title from contentdocument where not title like '%seo%'
```

How do I use the AND operator so that I can narrow down my search?

Thank you

Comment: Just add some brackets `select id, title from contentdocument where (not title like '%seo%') and (filetype = 'pdf')`

Comment: Thank you. That worked I am trying to mark your answer as correct but can't as you replied as comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add some brackets to join logical conditions, like so:

```
select id, title from contentdocument 
    where 
    (not title like '%seo%') and (filetype = 'pdf')
```